# How to tune mtry and number of trees simultaneously for a Random Forest Regression?

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, caret, hyperparameters

I am trying to tune parameters for a Random Forest using `caret` and method `ranger`. I have seen codes for tuning `mtry` using `tuneGrid`. And then using the resulted `mtry` to run loops and tune the number of trees (`num.tree`). However, I would like to know if it is possible to tune them both at the same time, to find out the best model between all possible combinations. I do not want to keep one argument constant and tune the other one, but both at the same time. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tune `ntree` as part of a `tuneGrid` for Random Forest in `caret`; only `mtry`, `splitrule` and `min.node.size` - see the tuning parameters for each model type here:
https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html

`ntree` can only be specified in `train`.